# Empty function to preserve jquery chains

Tags: jquery, function, placeholder, chaining, no-op

Is there a (maybe undocumented) placeholder like `$.noop` for the use in jQuery concatenations?

To use in something like the following:

```
$('selector')[true ? 'method' : '<function that does nothing>']().doSomething();
```

I've tried a lot and ended up with this:

```
$.fn.noop = function(){ return this; };
```

But maybe there's already such a function in the jQuery core?

Comment: @OlafDietsche Refers to window and not the selector.

Comment: what about `.filter("*")`?

Comment: @yckart I don't think there is a function like that

Comment: @JanDvorak A possible way, however unusable if no paramter can be passed.

Comment: And when I think that I'd be the only one using that level of premature optimization.. Well, I didn't get to the point of creating a noop solely for that though, I'd go with a conditional. Declaring a noop that returns the jQuery object itself as you've done is most concise way for your use-case though as calling other methods that would have no effect would add an unnecessary overhead and wouldn't make much sense to others reading your code.

Comment: I think there's a plugin for that. Check out the Iff jQuery plugin.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - it does create some overhead, but if it's not something you itend to use a lot, and nothing is passed to the function, something like `addClass` that does nothing when it's not passed a parameter does seem a lot simpler than creating a function that just returns `this`.

Comment: @adeneo what is wrong with creating a function that does exactly what you want? I find it much more semantic than as you've said, calling `addClass` to not add any class. Your call though.

Comment: Stick with `$.fn.noop = function(){return this;}`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - nothing is wrong with creating a function, but I'm a bit lazy, and I'm the only one reading my code, and if it where just once, I would'nt bother, but that's just me.

Comment: `$.fn.noop = Array.prototype.slice`

Comment: @adeneo Yes, that's how I often write my code, but I don't recommend it to others for reasons. `:P`

Comment: `$.fn.noop = $.fn.slice` (undocumented!)

Comment: I think you can use [`addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/), though that's not really the intended use ;)

Comment: @JanDvorak - That's just a method that is exactly the same as `slice()` so it probably works, but why not just use `slice()` instead ?

Comment: @adeneo is the empty `Array.prototype.slice()` documented? I'm afraid it's not.

Comment: the `$.fn.slice` method requires at least a starting index, otherwise it will just return `this`, so without params it should work.

Comment: @Yoshi `addBack` isn't an option in this way. Since it can't read the property `ownerDocument` of `null`.

Comment: @janDvorak Are there any dis/advantages by using `slice()` in place of `return this`? (except for the fact, that `return this` is faster)

Comment: @adeneo I still don't recommend its use in production code.

Comment: @yckart it's undocumented, so it could change anytime. Also, it's unreadable. Also, it requires there be no arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option one:

Use `$.fn.splice`. It's there and it's always present, but it's also undocumented (so it may not be present in the future), unreadable, and requires there be no arguments.

Option two:

`$.fn.noop = function(){return this}`. Reliable, readable, predictable, fast. About the only reason to prefer #1 is development time.

Option three (preferred): Use a plugin for conditionals, which are about the only reason to desire a chainable no-op, such as [the Iff plugin by Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-iff-plugin/) (or write your own).

Pro: turns

```
 ... [condition?'method':'noop']() ...
```

into:

```
 ... .iff(condition).method().end() ...
```

That is, it's more readable than #2, AND you're not restricted to one call. You can even traverse within `iff` or nest your conditionals as long as you properly unwind the stack.

Cons: it's a plugin, and you'll need to fetch it; it requires the methods you call are no-ops when operating on the empty collection. All standard jQuery functions (except `add`) are.